# adding text and backgrounds globally to pgfplots group plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have a group plot, but I would like to annotate the final pgfplots figure within the same `tikzfigure` environment, and I was wondering if this is possible. What I have so far is

```
\documentclass[border={10pt 10pt 10pt 10pt}]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{groupplot}[
    group style={
        group name=my plots,
        group size=4 by 3,
    },
        tick style={draw=none},
        ticks=none,
        ]

\nextgroupplot[]
\addplot3[surf, domain=0:1,y domain=0:1] {x};

\nextgroupplot[]
\addplot3[surf, domain=0:1,y domain=0:1] {y};

\nextgroupplot[]
\addplot3[surf, domain=0:1,y domain=0:1] {x*y};

\nextgroupplot[group/empty plot]

\nextgroupplot[]
\addplot3[surf, domain=0:1,y domain=0:1] {x^2};

\nextgroupplot[]
\addplot3[surf, domain=0:1,y domain=0:1] {y*2};

\nextgroupplot[]
\addplot3[surf, domain=0:1,y domain=0:1] {x^2*y^2)};

\nextgroupplot[group/empty plot]

\nextgroupplot[]
\addplot3[surf, domain=0:1,y domain=0:1] {x^3};

\nextgroupplot[]
\addplot3[surf, domain=0:1,y domain=0:1] {y^4};

\nextgroupplot[]
\addplot3[surf, domain=0:1,y domain=0:1] {x^2*y};

\nextgroupplot[]
\addplot3[surf, domain=0:1,y domain=0:1] {x*y^2};

\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I would like to have the final figure something like

[image]

where there's a background over a group of figures (gray box), and if this background can have rounded corners, and there's also text somewhere else in the plot.

Comment: You may not want to use groupplot for this case, and instead place each tikzpicture into a tabular cell or an array of minipages.  The default is to align the bottom edges of the plots, but you can use [baseline=(current bounding box.center)] or \raisebox.

Comment: I can't believe this can't be done using tikz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you are looking for something like the following?

```
% used PGFPlots v1.15
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usetikzlibrary{
        backgrounds,
        pgfplots.groupplots,
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    % draw the plots
    \begin{groupplot}[
        group style={
            group name=my plots,
            group size=4 by 3,
        },
        tick style={draw=none},
        ticks=none,
    ]
    \nextgroupplot[]
        \addplot3[surf, domain=0:1,y domain=0:1] {x};
    \nextgroupplot[]
        \addplot3[surf, domain=0:1,y domain=0:1] {y};
    \nextgroupplot[]
        \addplot3[surf, domain=0:1,y domain=0:1] {x*y};
    \nextgroupplot[group/empty plot]
    \nextgroupplot[]
        \addplot3[surf, domain=0:1,y domain=0:1] {x^2};
    \nextgroupplot[]
        \addplot3[surf, domain=0:1,y domain=0:1] {y*2};
    \nextgroupplot[]
        \addplot3[surf, domain=0:1,y domain=0:1] {x^2*y^2)};
    \nextgroupplot[group/empty plot]
    \nextgroupplot[]
        \addplot3[surf, domain=0:1,y domain=0:1] {x^3};
    \nextgroupplot[]
        \addplot3[surf, domain=0:1,y domain=0:1] {y^4};
    \nextgroupplot[]
        \addplot3[surf, domain=0:1,y domain=0:1] {x^2*y};
    \nextgroupplot[]
        \addplot3[surf, domain=0:1,y domain=0:1] {x*y^2};
    \end{groupplot}

    % draw the text nodes
    \node at (my plots c4r1) {text1};
    \node [
        % change node dimensions to fit the size of the plots
        % (Since the axis width and height weren't changed they are still
        %  the default values. But you didn't draw any axis labels, so the
        %  extra reserved space for that isn't needed (see the manual).)
        text width=\axisdefaultwidth - 45pt,
        minimum width=\axisdefaultwidth - 45pt,
        minimum height=\axisdefaultheight - 45pt,
        align=justify,
%        % ---------------------------------------------------------------------
%        % for debugging purposes only
%        draw,
%        % ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    ] at (my plots c4r2) {
        this is a bit lengthier text to show that you are not limited to
        some short stuff here.
    };

    % draw the background rectangles
    \begin{scope}[
        on background layer,
        rounded corners=15pt,
    ]
            \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\Shift}{10pt}
        \fill [black!10]
            ([shift={(-\Shift,\Shift)}] my plots c1r1.north west)
                rectangle
            ([shift={(\Shift,-\Shift)}] my plots c2r2.south east)
        ;
        \fill [blue!50!red!25!white]
            ([shift={(-\Shift,\Shift)}] my plots c4r3.north west)
                rectangle
            ([shift={(\Shift,-\Shift)}] my plots c4r3.south east)
        ;
    \end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: This is exactly what I had in mind. Great! Thank you so much.

Comment: @aaragon, you are welcome.